# Missing Items in Software Centre

Tags: software-center

I've been setting up a couple of computers with Ubuntu, and making sure they all have a couple of packages I need. When I looked for the packages in the software centre on most of them they were there, but on a couple they were nowhere to be found. I got them just fine using apt-get, but it seemed odd that the selection in the software centre was inconsistent between otherwise identical computers.

Comment: About what items do you mean?

Comment: The ones I noticed were netcat and ssh, although I'm sure there were more that I wasn't looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next images maybe will give you an idea:

[image: No software sources]

---

[image: Software sources]

So, the software sources must to be the same on all computers about that you speak if you want to find the same things everywhere in those computers in **Ubuntu Software Centre**.

To open and select software source, search for **Software & Updates** in **Dash**.

Also, for troubleshooting, a good general procedure not only for Ubuntu Software Centre is to run next set of commands from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

More about: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSoftwareCenter.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Now I'm just wondering why the computers had different default software source settings when I set them all up in the same way...